# Evaluating the limit of some undefined trigonometric function using Squeeze theorem

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I want to know how to do a problem like this. What steps are taken and why.

I have some function:

$$
\lim_{h\to3} \ \sin{\left(\frac{1}{h-3}\right)} \ e^h \ (h-3)^2
$$

Comment: If you knew the following inequality $\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \leq 1$, could you tackle this problem?

Comment: Try drawing a graph of @rt6's solution to see what is really going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that $-1\leq \sin(x)\leq 1$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

It follows then for every value of $h\in \mathbb{R}$ except at $h=3$,

$$-e^h(h-3)^2\leq \sin\left(\frac{1}{h-3}\right)e^h(h-3)^2\leq e^h(h-3)^2$$

We can now apply the squeeze theorem as $h$ tends to $3$ to obtain that the desired limit is zero.